# How to minimize Nelson-Siegel parametric form

Tags: programming, fixed-income, bond, yield-curve, optimization

**Problem**
I am given the following function to minimize  (w.r.t. $\theta$)
$$f= \sum_{k=1}^5 \Big [ \sum_{i=1}^{N_k} CF_{k, i} \cdot e^{-r(t_{k, i}, \theta)\cdot t_{k, i}} - P_k^* \Big]^2$$
where $\theta = (\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2, \lambda)$ and
$$ r(t, \theta) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \big(\frac{1-e^{-\frac{t}{\lambda}}}{\frac{t}{\lambda}} \big) +  \beta_2 \big(\frac{1-e^{-\frac{t}{\lambda}}}{\frac{t}{\lambda}} - e^{-\frac{t}{\lambda}} \big)$$

**Context**
We are given 5 bonds, their cashflows, $CF_{k, i}$, and market price, $P_k^*$. All these values are given to us as numbers.

**My attempt**
I tried to apply Newton's Method using python. However, I am pretty sure that this method is not applicable here, and I need another minimization algorithm.

Could anyone suggest which algorithm is the best for such a function?
?

Answer (score 5):

When we worked with that model several years go, we used Differential Evolution and it worked very well. See [Calibrating the Nelson-Siegel-Svensson Model](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1676747). At least in the standard version, a best-of-many gradient searches (with random initial values) also worked well. See [A Note on 'Good Starting Values' in Numerical Optimisation](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1620083). If you were willing to use R as well, there are many code examples in the [NMOF package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I built something like you attempted here to estimate yield curves for various sectors using Bbg bond quotes years ago in VBA. For the calibration of the parameters I used Nelder Mead. It doesn't need the first and second derivative or estimators of it such as Newton-Ralphson and such.